# openvswitch, open-flow, rate limiting

Tags: openflow, openvswitch

I ve been able to apply rate limiting and Qos policy in OpenVswitch by using openflow rules , but i am actually wondering if :

Using the same bridge and same ports apply different QOS or Traffic Rate limiting to specific ip adresses ?

any leads on that ?

do  the open flow syntax support filtered by ip traffic resubmission ?

Thanks

Alex,

Answer (score 0):

Seems that openflow matcher's can do the job

Thanks